# How I can prevent by site from attacks

Tags: website

I'm aware that by sending frequent requests to my site from a loop, some body can put my site down. How I can prevent that? Any ideas will really help me.

Comment: This is really a serverfault question. In the meantime you might want to Google the term DOS or "Denial of Service" attacks for more information. This isn't going to be a quick and easy answer.

Comment: `man iptables` is your friend

Comment: In addition to JohnFx comment, you may also Google for DDOS or "Distributed Denial of Service" attacks for even more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point blank.  There's no way to "stop" an attack.  But you can limit the effectiveness.  There are also multiple types of DDoS attacks so you could go the cover all bases route and plan for every possible attack; even ones that are very rarely used. However the attack that has been making most headlines(Visa/Mastercard/Paypal) was the LOIC(Low Orbit Ion Cannon) attack which can utilize three different aspects - TCP, UDP, and HTTP GET requests.  Now you can make a firewall rule to detect UDP and TCP versions of LOIC, but that can then place great overhead on your firewall(depending on how big the hive is).  Or you can use a hashlimit on iptables so that you're able to limit the number of packets per minute.  Your question is extremely vague so research a bit more to isolate what you're looking for and go from there.